# How to find element using type in Selenium and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have the below html code.

```
<div align="center">
    <input type="file" name="filePath"><br>
    <input type="Submit" value="Upload File"><br>
</div>
```

I am trying to find the two elements "file" and "submit" using Selenium with Python. Below is the code I have tried to use.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# create a new Firefox session
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Maximize the browser window
driver.maximize_window()

# Enter the url to load
driver.get("<<MY PAGE TO LOAD>>")

# Wait for the page to load
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

# find the upload file type and pass a test value
upload_field = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('file')
upload_field.clear()
upload_field.send_keys("test")
```

When I run this code, I am able to load the page successfully in the Chrome browser but I get the below exception.

```
# Exception when trying to get element by type
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\TEST\Desktop\Test.py", line 33, in <module>
    upload_field = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('file')
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 453, in find_element_by_partial_link_text
    return self.find_element(by=By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, value=link_text)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 955, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 237, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"partial link text","selector":"file"}
  (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.132)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528161 (5b82f2d2aae0ca24b877009200ced9065a772e73),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
```

I looked at the solution provided [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/15509/selenium-how-to-identify-an-object-by-its-type) but this too is throwing an error. I am currently using Python 3.6.4 x64 with Selenium 3.8.1. My OS is Windows 7 x64 bit. How can I get elements with 'type' in html?

Comment: Why don't you try the complete xpath(//input[@name='filePath']) , instead of partial text.

Comment: A bit off-topic, but instead of using `implicitly_wait` use [explicit wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits). It'll be faster and more reliable.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Checkout [the docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) on finding elements. I find xpaths or css selectors particularly powerful because they are extremely generalizable.

#### xpath

```
upload_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']")
```

#### css selector

```
upload_field = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='filePath'][type='file']")
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex. I used the `driver.find_element_by_xpath` method for finding both elements `file` and `Submit`. It worked flawlessly. I do have one more follow up query. The `file` element expects a file to be passed. What if I wanted the user to select the file of his choice rather than hardcoding it in the code?

Comment: @Code_Sipra This should pop up a dialog where the user can select a file... You might want to ask a new question if you are having trouble with it!

Comment: Well it does not seem to be popping up the dialog box. But as you suggested, I can use 'tkinter` to make the user provide the path of the upload file separately. Thanks for the inputs and guidance. This solves all my problems with reading elements in selenium.

Comment: @Code_Sipra Glad to hear it!

Comment: sorry but I have another query. Normally, the file to be uploaded would be huge. ~50-100mb size. The system does not show any 'upload completed' message once a file is uploaded. How to I ensure that the entire file is completely uploaded before I click the submit button? Do I need to raise this as a separate question in SO?

Comment: @Code_Sipra I don't know. You probably want to post a new question as this one is about selenium... You will get better responses if you have a question tagged with `html`.

Answer (score 4):

`find_element_by_partial_link_text` looks for the element **text**. In addition, it works only on `<a>` tags. For example, `driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('file')` will match the following html

```
<a type="file" name="filePath">file</a>
```

But not your html as the element has no text.

You could locate the element by the `name` attribute instead

```
driver.find_element_by_name('filePath')
```

Comment: Thanks @Guy, this works for the element `file`. It does not work for the element `Submit`.

Comment: @Code_Sipra Because submit doesn't have `name` attribute. You can use `css_selector` to locate by `value`, `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[value="Upload File"]')`

Comment: `find_element_by_partial_link_text()` works with **links only (e.g. `<a ...>...</a>`)**! Update your answer appropriately to not confuse OP

Answer (score 1):

Its not the proper way to use the <kbd>partial text</kbd> in selenium .
Please go through the link to understand how to use partial link https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/how-to-locate-element-by-link-text-and-partial-link-text-locator/

Answer to your question.
Use the other attribute like name to identify the locator.

Otherwise try this locator "//input[@name='filePath']"

Comment: thanks for the inputs @Pradeep hebbar. I used the `driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text` incorrectly in this case. Appreciate you sharing the link on how it can be used correctly. It may help me in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Method `driver.find_element_by_css_selector` is now deprecated in selenium >=4.3.0

From https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/a4995e2c096239b42c373f26498a6c9bb4f2b3e7/py/CHANGES

> Selenium 4.3.0
>
> - Deprecated find_element_by_* and find_elements_by_* are now removed (#10712)

New method is:

```bash
driver.find_element('xpath', '//button[text()="Some text"]')
```

From https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html