# ValueError: No tables found while I am scraping webpages

Tags: python, web-scraping

I need to read a list of webpages. For instance I have a web that works

```
url1 = 'https://www.sia.ch/en/membership/member-directory/m/207778/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/massaro/research/Valeria/chromedriver 2')
driver.get(url1)
html = driver.page_source
html = str(html).replace('<br />', '::')
df1 = pd.read_html(html)[0].iloc[[0,2],1]
```

than I have another page for which I get the error

```
url2 = 'https://www.sia.ch/en/membership/member-directory/m/105531/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/massaro/research/Valeria/chromedriver 2')
driver.get(url2)
html = driver.page_source
html = str(html).replace('<br />', '::')
df1 = pd.read_html(html)[0].iloc[[0,2],1]

ValueError: No tables found
```

I would like to have a condition to skip webpages that have no tables in order to avoid the error.

Comment: But you have such a condition. Pages without tables will raise `ValueError`. That is a testable condition.

Comment: @usr2564301 yes but how can I check it before to get the error?

Comment: "Before", no you don't. Catching errors is a [standard procedure in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

Answer (score 0):

[Maybe this will help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48365252/how-to-find-element-using-type-in-selenium-and-python) You could check if the value returned by this is truthy/falsy:

```
if driver.find_element_by_css_selector("table"):
   # rest of your code here
```

Something along those lines?